# Check wether a InApp is purchased

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

in the app I am developing it is possible to buy additional Features. After I uninstall the app the shared preferences are gone. How can I check wether I bought the inApp-Product after a new installation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Restore Transactions request to obtain information about billed items. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type).

Comment: even i am getting stuck with this.In dungeons example, onRestoreTransactionsResponse uses only shared preferences.Then how can we get the billed items ?

Answer (score 2):

you should use restore transaction.if use restore transaction it is possible but your products must be MANAGED products .for more details
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/sjGejJAF7FM